# Cache my static data in server for all user C#

Tags: c#

I want to cache some static data in server. if any user request for same data cache should return that.

if i go with HttpContext.cache, it will vary by user. please help me how to do that in c#?

What I have tried:

```
HttpContext.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, Sonarresult, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(Timeduration), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

i tried this but for all users will store into cache. i dont want that. first user only has to store it.

Comment: [Use the application cache.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597.aspx)

Comment: Can you explain me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Using the application cache just like you would a session variable can do the trick for you.

e.g.

```
// get
string message = Application["somemessage"].ToString();
```

will be the same for all users.

to elaborate further, be careful where on your code you set the value for application variables because once they change, they will change for all.

```
// set
Application["somemessage"] = "your message";
```

Global.asax would be a could place to set the value of Application variables if they never change:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Code that runs on application startup

  // here we set the value every time the application starts
  Application["somemessage"] = "your message";

  // the following line will get the SiteName from the web.config setting section
  Application["SiteName"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteName"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use application cache to do this.

```
void Application_Start ()
  {
      _cache = Context.Cache;  
      _cache.Insert ("mycahce", mystaticvariabledata, null,
      Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
      CacheItemPriority.Default,null);
  }
```